# Placing a pre-determined number of agents in random places in a polyline in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I have a model in which I place agents in a random locations within different polyline shapes. This works fine. I use the following function, which is called in the 'On startup' field of my agent:

```
double rand = uniform(1);
double x;
double y;

if(rand <=  0.5) /// 
    do {
        x = 0, 100 );
        y = 0, 100 );
    } while( ! pl_FirstShape.contains( x, y ) );
else if(rand > 0.5) /// 
    do {
        x = uniform( 0, 100 );
        y = uniform( 0, 100 );
    } while( ! pl_SecondShape.contains( x, y ) );
```

The above code will place different amount of agents in each polyline for different runs. This is of course, expected. However, I would like to place a specific number of agents in each polyline at random locations. I am not very familiar with do-while loops so I have not found a solution myself. I tried including a counter like this:

```
int counter = 0;
if(counter < 100) /// 
    do {
        x = uniform(0, 100 );
        y = uniform(0, 100 );
        counter++;
    } while( ! pl_FirstShape.contains( x, y ) );
```

While the code compiles without error, I do not see any of my agents appear in these polyline shapes. Who can help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a piece of code that does what I want. `v_counter` is a global
variable in Main that keeps track of the number of agents generated. Parameters `p_CountAgentsFirstShape` and `p_CountAgentsSecondShape` are also in Main and contain the number of agents I want in each shape.

```
double x = 0;
double y = 0;

if(v_counter <= p_CountAgentsFirstShape) {
    do {
        x = uniform( 0,100 );
        y = uniform(0, 100);
        if(pl_FirstShape.contains(x, y)) {
            v_counter = v_counter + 1;
            }
        } while( ! pl_FirstShape.contains( x, y ) );
}
else if(v_counter >= p_CountAgentsFirstShape & v_counter <= p_CountAgentsSecondShape){ 
    do {
        x = uniform(0, 100);
        y = uniform(0, 100);
        if(pl_SecondShape.contains(x, y)) {
            v_counter= v_counter+ 1;
            }
    } while( ! pl_SecondShape.contains( x, y ) );
}
else
    do {
        x = uniform(0, 100);
        y = uniform(0, 100);
    } while( ! countrybounds.contains( x, y ) );

agent.setXY( x, y );
```

Of course, functionizing the contents of the do-while loop is preferred to reduce repitition.